# Way to Fix Lines behind title when Title is Two Lines Long

Tags: css, html

My CSS is set up so that my post titles have two red lines behind the text (the line disappears behind the text). The effect works fine when the title is one line, but when it goes onto a second line, the effect goes kind of wonky. You can check it out here:

http://onedirectionconnection.com/2013/08/one-direction-win-song-of-the-summer/

I just want the lines in the back to move to the middle of the div and just display at the ends of the longest line of the title (like it does on the left in the page above).

If anyone could help me figure out how to fix this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. I've made a jsfiddle to help here: http://jsfiddle.net/tC99W/

Here's my CSS:

```
.section-title{
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: #FFF 1px 1px,#ccc 2px 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.section-title:before, .section-title:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 4px;
    content: '\a0';
    border-bottom: 3px solid #DA5969;
    border-top: 1px solid #DA5969;
    box-sizing: content-box; /* + vendor specific versions here */
}
.section-title:before {
    margin-left: -52%;
    text-align: right;
}
.section-title:after {
    margin-left:2%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="section-title">The Title Goes Here</h1>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a `<div>` between your `.container` and your `.section-title` and this `<div>` should have the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes similarly to what you've already done.

The additional `<div>` (let's call it `.title-container`) wrapping around the `.section-title` will shrink and grow both in width and height with the text inside it. Also both the `.title-container` and `.section-title` should be displayed as `inline-block` in order to center them, add margin/padding and to grow/shrink according to text.

I've also moved some of the CSS rules fromthe `.section-title` to `.title-container`

Look at the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grim/tC99W/3/, it's probably easier to understand this way.

**EDIT: Expanding lines to the edge of container:**
This is another updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tC99W/10/

Basically you should let the `.title-container` expand so it shouldn't be an `inline-block` but rather a `block` element.
Also the borders should be wider (I've put `width: 50%;` but it's actually a bit long).
The most important part is to play with the `z-index` of the title and the `:before` and `:after` elements.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to figure this out. I like where the lines are positioned, but the only problem is, when the title is short, the red lines move in with the text instead of expanding out to the edges of the container. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/tC99W/8/ Do you know of any way to make the lines change size depending on the content of the title?

Comment: I thought you wanted to have the lines with a specific width and moving with the text. In any case, I've edited my answer; this should work. I haven't tested it on different browsers so feedback about this would be nice.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick! I checked this as the answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to add another box for that.
Take a look at that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/tC99W/4/)

Here are the relevant changes.

```
.section-title:before, .section-title:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    height: 4px;
    width: 4%;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 3px solid #DA5969;
    border-top: 1px solid #DA5969;
}
.section-title:before {
    left:0;
}
.section-title:after {
    right:0;
}
```

Edit: it looks ugly with one line.

Assuming that the header comes always first inside the container, you can do something like [**That**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/tC99W/6/) (again, without adding another container).
But notice that it's depending on the assumption.
so you should use something like grim's solution.

Comment: Thanks so much! I like the way this method looks when the title does span onto two lines, but the issue is, when it's a short title, the red lines stay out near the margins - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/tC99W/7/ Would you know of any way to remedy this?